# Problema con ejecución de funciones

Tags: javascript, funciones

Actualmente estoy haciendo una librería y quisiera saber el porque al momento de llamar mis funciones me las remplaza y solo pone los datos o la información que le doy de la ultima función declarada, la única que me respeta es la función base que es stStyle pero si le agrego las demás pasa ese error y solo ejecuta la ultima.

**CODIGO**

```
function styleTxt (selector) {
  const obj = {
    getElement (selector) {
      return document.querySelector(selector)
    },
    stStyle (color, bgColor) {
      document.onmouseup = function () {
        if (window.getSelection().toString().length > 0) {
          window
            .getSelection()
            .getRangeAt(0)
            .surroundContents(createSpanTag())
          const selectedElement = document.getElementById(`stElement${auto}`)
          selectedElement.style.color = color
          selectedElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor
          window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
          auto++
        }
      }
      return this
    },
    stSize (ftSize) {
      document.onclick = () => {
        const selectedElement = document.getElementById(`stElement${auto - 1}`)
        selectedElement.style.fontSize = `${ftSize}px`
      }
      return this
    },
    txtBold () {
      document.onclick = () => {
        const selectedElement = document.getElementById(`stElement${auto - 1}`)
        selectedElement.style.fontWeight = 'bolder'
      }
      return this
    },
    stBorder () {
      document.onclick = () => {
        const selectedElement = document.getElementById(`stElement${auto - 1}`)
        selectedElement.style.border = '5px solid black'
      }
      return this
    }
  }

  return obj
}
```

**EJEMPLO**

```
styleTxt('#element').stStyle('white', 'orange').stSize(20).txtBold().stBorder()
```

Comment: mas o menos que deseas que haga tu libreria? ya que no entiendo del todo lo que quieres hacer!

Comment: @Bryro que mande a llamar las funciones de forma que estas le den caracteristicas al elemento seleccionado con el id o la clase, similar a lo que sucede con jquery como te puedes dar cuenta. La primera funcion llamada stStyle es obligatoria pero en cuanto a las demas son opcionales y si quieres puedes agregarlas todas o ninguna dependiendo del caso lo cual le dara nuevas caracteristicas de diseño al elemento.